# Could not find class in JUnit 4.11

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, java-7

First of all,
I've looked at all of the similar questions on stack overflow and nothing has worked for me yet.
Just trying to get JUnit to work with a simple example from the book JUnit in Action 2nd Edition by Peter Tahchiev.

Calculator.java

```
public class Calculator {
    public double add(double number1, double number2) {
        return number1 + number2;
    }
}
```

CalculatorTest.java

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;

public class CalculatorTest {

    @Test
    public void testAdd() {
        Calculator calc = new Calculator();
        double result = calc.add(1,1);
        assertEquals(2, result,0);
    }
}
```

My folder:
[image: Current Folder]

I compile with:

```
javac -cp junit-4.11.jar *.java
```

My folder after compiling:
[image: Current Folder after compiling]

I Try to Run Test with:

```
java -cp junit-4.11.jar;hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;. org.junit.runner.JUnitCore CalculatorTest
```

This is my output:

[image: Output]

When I try to run the individual classes the jre finds them but throws a no main method error which is expected:

```
java Calculator
java CalculatorTest
```

Outputs(which were expected, but it found the classes):
[image: Error 1]
[image: Error 2]

Any ideas how I can get JUnit/whatever it is to behave?

[EDIT]
I run all commands in `C:\Users\Zach\Documents\docs\Code\JUnit`
The screenshots above are of the same folder.
I'm using `jdk1.7.0_45` and `jre7`
I'm using Windows 7 Professional N 64 - bit

I ran the java command using -verbose:class and there were no errors except the one on line 426 which is seen below:
[image: verbose error]

Comment: I've typed the exact commands you listed with the files you listed and it works on Windows.  I replaced the ; with : and ran it on Linux and it worked just fine.  Something must be specific to your environment.  What directory are you in when you run the second command (the java command)?

Comment: Added directory, jdk, jre, and OS

Comment: You could try running with -verbose:class and see if that indicates anything to you.

Comment: Added -verbose:class info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fascinating.  Anyways, it appears you have junit-4.11.jar in lib/ext in your JRE.  This location takes preference over the classpath and classes loaded in this directory are loaded in a separate classloader.

That lib/ext classloader can't see the class loaded by the classpath classloader and thus JUnit can't see your code.  If you are using Junit from the command line in this fashion it is probably best not to put the jar in your lib/ext folder.  If you were running it programmatically (e.g. JUnitCore.runClasses(...)) then you could load your classes using the normal classloader and pass them to JUnit in the secluded classloader and all would be good.

So, short answer is probably to remove the junit jar from the lib/ext folder provided you know why it was in there in the first place and that reason is no longer valid.

Comment: I removed it, reset everything and did everything. it works.
Turn power off, turn power on.